# Is it possible to override type configuration in the di.xml of a module in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, overrides, dependency-injection, di, construct

I want to override the file **"Fooman\EmailAttachments\Observer\AbstractSendInvoiceObserver"**.

Here is the code in the di.xml.

```
<!-- module introduced preferences -->
<preference for="Fooman\EmailAttachments\Model\Api\AttachmentContainerInterface"
            type="Fooman\EmailAttachments\Model\AttachmentContainer"/>

<type name="\Fooman\EmailAttachments\Observer\AbstractSendOrderObserver">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="pdfRenderer" xsi:type="object">\Fooman\EmailAttachments\Model\NoneRenderer</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>


<virtualType name="fooman_emailattachments_invoice_pdf_renderer" type="\Fooman\EmailAttachments\Model\PdfRenderer">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="pdfRenderer" xsi:type="object">\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
<type name="\Fooman\EmailAttachments\Observer\AbstractSendInvoiceObserver">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="pdfRenderer" xsi:type="object">fooman_emailattachments_invoice_pdf_renderer</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>

<virtualType name="fooman_emailattachments_shipment_pdf_renderer" type="\Fooman\EmailAttachments\Model\PdfRenderer">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="pdfRenderer" xsi:type="object">\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Shipment</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
<type name="\Fooman\EmailAttachments\Observer\AbstractSendShipmentObserver">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="pdfRenderer" xsi:type="object">fooman_emailattachments_shipment_pdf_renderer</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>

<type name="\Fooman\EmailAttachments\Observer\AbstractSendInvoiceShipmentObserver">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="pdfRenderer" xsi:type="object">fooman_emailattachments_invoice_pdf_renderer</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>

<virtualType name="fooman_emailattachments_creditmemo_pdf_renderer" type="\Fooman\EmailAttachments\Model\PdfRenderer">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="pdfRenderer" xsi:type="object">\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Creditmemo</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
<type name="\Fooman\EmailAttachments\Observer\AbstractSendCreditmemoObserver">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="pdfRenderer" xsi:type="object">fooman_emailattachments_creditmemo_pdf_renderer</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Php file

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Fooman\EmailAttachments\Observer;

    class AbstractSendInvoiceObserver extends AbstractObserver
{
    const XML_PATH_ATTACH_PDF = 'sales_email/invoice/attachpdf';
    const XML_PATH_ATTACH_AGREEMENT = 'sales_email/invoice/attachagreement';

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        /**
         * @var \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\InvoiceInterface $invoice
         */
        $invoice = $observer->getInvoice();
        if ($this->pdfRenderer->canRender()
            && $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
                static::XML_PATH_ATTACH_PDF,
                \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                $invoice->getStoreId()
            )
        ) {
            $this->contentAttacher->addPdf(
                $this->pdfRenderer->getPdfAsString([$invoice]),
                $this->pdfRenderer->getFileName(__('Invoice') . $invoice->getIncrementId()),
                $observer->getAttachmentContainer()
            );
        }

        if ($this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            static::XML_PATH_ATTACH_AGREEMENT,
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            $invoice->getStoreId()
        )
        ) {
            $this->attachTermsAndConditions($invoice->getStoreId(), $observer->getAttachmentContainer());
        }
    }
}
```

How can I override this in my module?

Comment: Please share the entire `di.xml` file so we can understand where the object is coming from.

Comment: @Msquare updated the di.xml

Comment: Can you please inform me which `pdfRenderer` you need to override?

Comment: you can directly overite using preferences https://magefan.com/blog/magento-2-preferences

Comment: @Msquare I need to override this file Fooman\EmailAttachments\Observer\AbstractSendInvoiceObserver

Comment: @Msquare direct preference is not worked

Comment: Please provide the module zip file so I can examine it further and provide you with a solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151216/discussion-between-jancy-abraham-and-msquare).

Comment: @Msquare Thank you for the support, Shared the details in the chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options:

1. completely replace Observer
2. add a plugin on the Observer's execute method

As the Observer class only has the single execute method the first option I think is easier to read.

To implement option 1 make sure to create a separate module that has a sequence that sorts it after Fooman_EmailAttachments. Then in your `etc/events.xml` include

```
    <!--Invoice Emails-->
    <event name="fooman_emailattachments_before_send_invoice">
        <observer name="fooman_emailattachments_before_send_invoice_observer"
                  instance="Custom\FoomanEmailAttachments\Observer\BeforeSendInvoiceObserver"/>
    </event>
    <event name="fooman_emailattachments_before_send_invoice_comment">
        <observer name="fooman_emailattachments_before_send_invoice_comment_observer"
                  instance="Custom\FoomanEmailAttachments\Observer\BeforeSendInvoiceCommentObserver"/>
    </event>
```

the above assumes your module is called `Custom_FoomanEmailAttachments`. You can then provide your own implementation for the observer.